# CWMP CPE (Client) implementation

Tags: soap, protocols, easycwmp

I am trying to get the TR-069/CWMP protocol up and running. I have found an open source ACS server called openACS. My problem is the CPE, there does not seem to be any open source CPE implementations around. I have found a few projects but none are alive. I was wondering if anyone knows about any full CPE implementation? Also, Does anyone know how much work would be involved in implementing the protocol myself?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't help you with TR-069 but I can tell you that, while OpenACS is a fantastic piece of software, the "ACS" in OpenACS stands for "Architecture Community System" not "Auto Configuration Servers", so is probably not useful for you in this case. :-) best of luck
Brian

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for the reply but the OpenACS I am talking about IS an auto configuration server, there are two projects called OpenACS out there :)

Comment: Hey you're right - it's on Sourceforge. That's news to me! Thanks for the heads-up. Good luck with CPE search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had implemented a generic stand alone CWMP client in pure C before 5-6 years. It was a project for my University (there is a publication for that http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F30%2F34592%2F01649657.pdf%3Farnumber%3D1649657&authDecision=-203)

Well, actually, if you read the paper you'll see that we propose there a methodology for creating (instantiating) CWMP clients through Java. You could use a java program to define the model of the CWMP client and create a configuration file which would be used by the generic CWMP client. After that you used some hooks to define what should be done on the Set or Get of each parameter of the model.

If I remember correctly, the CWMP client implemented most of the requirements of the TR-69 document and you could add its model (set and get parameters) easily without using the Java tools.

If you feel that it could help you and want to continue the CWMP client, I would gladly send to you (or upload somehere) the full source code. However **I warn you** - I don't remember anything about that project so I can't answer any questions !

Concerning the implementation time, it took me around 2-3 months. I had implemented my own HTTP server and SOAP parser / generator (using IXML for XML parsing). It wasn't anything fancy but it was working - it even supported SSL through OpenSSL !

Also, I've created a bitbucket repository containing the source code of the client: http://bitbucket.org/spapas/cwmpclient. I hope it's helpful - if it is, just add a reference to the original project

Comment: Hi Serafeim, Thanks for your reply. Unfortunatly, I can't access your publication because I don't have an account on ieeexplore. However, It would be great if I could see the source code for your client. If you are able to upload it somewhere that would be excellent. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I've created a bitbucket repository containing the source code of the client: https://bitbucket.org/spapas/cwmpclient/. I hope it's helpful - if it is, just add a reference to the original project.

Comment: I was looking through the code and I have to say its very well written and easy to understand. I know you said you don't remember anything about it but I'm just slightly confused about something. From looking through the code I noticed you have implemented parsing functions for the Inform RPC and other RPC's that only the ACS would need to parse. Was your original intention to create both a CPE and ACS?

Comment: Hi toc777, I'm glad you find it useful! You are right, there are methods for parsing and creating both Inform and InformResponse messages (also for GetParameterNames, GetParameterValues, SetParameterValues). This is because I was using these functions to create sample xmls with requests and responses of these messages to use them in some experiments. You will see that, for GetRPCMethods or Reboot message, I have code that parses only the request and creates only the response. I haven't implemented an ACS in C (however I had implemented a very simple ACS in Java for testing purposes!)...

Answer (score 2):

I recently developed GPLv2 TR-069 (cwmp) client called freecwmp. You can get it here:

http://www.freecwmp.org/

Comment: Is being used anywhere? Are any products using this client? The site does not give an insight into who may be using this stack.

Answer (score 2):

we developed a full complete open source called [easycwmp](/questions/tagged/easycwmp). please visit http://www.easycwmp.org for more details and to download the source

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that there is no actively developed CWMP client. freecwmp is under active development and it is GPLv2 licensed; it is already used in production. Main focus is on OpenWrt platform.

Also I have started doing server side ACS and CWMP proxy. More information can be found on the project web page: http://freeacs-ng.org/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is there are no fully implemented open source CPE implementations. There does not seem to be any open source implementations in progress either. Also, I believe there will be quite a lot of work involved in creating my own implementation.