# recv() error C/C++ socket programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, tcp

I'm writing the CWMP client for TR-069 Server. I'm basing my client's code on this topic (there's also a source code link in the topic)

[CWMP CPE (Client) implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793690/cwmp-cpe-client-implementation)

I have encountered a weird issue that recv() doesn't read the data sent! I've checked the data I'm sending and it's correct. I've installed a Wireshark on a server side and it captures the packets with the same very data client sent. I'm digging into TR-069 ACS source code and I've tried to change the listening socket mode to NON_BLOCK - no use.

Socket definition source:

```
int make_socket(unsigned int port)
{
  int sock;
  struct sockaddr_in name;
  sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
  {
    logtr("ACS Server:", "Can not create socket", ERROR, conferr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  name.sin_family = AF_INET;
  name.sin_port = htons(port);
  name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof(name)) < 0)
  {
    // perror ("bind");
    logtr("ACS Server:", "Can not bind ", ERROR, conferr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return sock;
}
```

Processing:

```
void connection(int sock)
{
  if (listen(sock, 10) < 0)
  {
    //perror ("listen");
    logtr("ACS Server:", "Can not listen socket", ERROR, conferr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  FD_ZERO(&active_fd_set);
  FD_SET(sock, &active_fd_set);

  //  int status = 3;

  while (1)
  {
    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    read_fd_set = active_fd_set;
    if (select(FD_SETSIZE + 1, &read_fd_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout) < 0)
    {
      //perror ("Select");
      logtr("ACS Server:", "Can not select socket", ERROR, conferr);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= FD_SETSIZE; ++i)
      if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fd_set))
      {
        if (i == sock)
        {
          size = sizeof(clientname);
          newfd1 = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &clientname, &size);
          if (newfd1 < 0)
          {
            //perror ("accept");
            logtr("ACS Server:", "Can not accept socket", ERROR, conferr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
          /*
           fprintf (stderr,"Server: connect from host %s, port %i\n",
           (char*)inet_ntoa(clientname.sin_addr),
           ntohs(clientname.sin_port));
           */
          char info[128];
          sprintf(info, "Server: connect from host %s, port %i\n",
              (char*) inet_ntoa(clientname.sin_addr),
              ntohs(clientname.sin_port));
          trace(info);

          FD_SET(newfd1, &active_fd_set);

          memset(fileCBuff[i].fileContBuff, 0,
              sizeof(fileCBuff[i].fileContBuff));
          out_get_param_value0 = 0;
          out_get_param_value1 = 0;
          c_reboot = 0;
          c_download = 0;
          noSqlError = 0;

        }
        else
        {
          send_recive_socket(i);
        }
      }
  }
}
```

And finally where it fails:

```
void send_recive_socket( int i )
{
  if( read_from_client(i) < 0 )
  {
    CLOSECONNECTION: 
    close(i);
    FD_CLR (i,&active_fd_set);
//printf("\nClose connection ......\n");\   
  }
  else 
  {  
    ...

int read_from_client( int fileDesc )
{
  int nbytes;
  memset( buffer,0,READ_MSG_SIZE );
  nbytes = recv(fileDesc, buffer, READ_MSG_SIZE,0);//reade data from client
  if( nbytes <= 0 )
  {
    logtr("ACS Server:","Wait Data from TR069 Client ", ERROR, conferr);
   // printf("\nNo data from client");
   // perror ("Read ...");
    return -1;
   }
   else
   {
    ...
```

I suppose this is the place because whenever I halt the client's execution the log receives

```
ACS Server: Wait Data from TR069 Client ERROR servHelper.c read_from_client
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code you show here is designed to log an error whenever a client disconnects for whatever reason. Are you sure you're sending data in the correct format, and that the server isn't simply in a state where it waits for more data, since what you've already sent it is incorrect ? Also, changing the socket to non-blocking sounds like a bad idea without also handling the fact that recv/send and so on can thus fail with EWOULDBLOCK.

Comment: How does your code handle the case of `recv()` returning a value `>0` and `<READ_MSG_SIZE` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recv` may return `-1` with `errno` set to `EINTR` when a signal arrives.  This is a transient failure and doesn't indicate any problem with your socket connection.  You probably want to ignore this error and try calling `recv` again.  The easiest way to do this on Linux is to use the [TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Interrupted-Primitives.html) macro

```
nbytes = TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(recv(fileDesc, buffer, READ_MSG_SIZE,0));
```

This will call `recv` repeatedly until it returns something other than `nbytes==-1 && errno==EINTR`