# TR-069 cwmp client implementation: open sources comparison

Tags: soap, protocols, network-protocols, easycwmp

I m looking for an open source implementation for the TR-069 cwmp client (CPE). I want to install it on a box containing OpenWRT firmware

I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793690/cwmp-cpe-client-implementation) in which there is many open source suggestion.

I make also a search on the net and I found the following open sources:

- [netcwmp](http://code.google.com/p/netcwmp/)
- [EasyCwmp](http://www.easycwmp.org)
- [freecwmp](http://www.freecwmp.org)
- [cwmpclient](http://bitbucket.org/spapas/cwmpclient)
- [open-tr069](http://code.google.com/p/open-tr069/)

I want to know what's the opensource which is complete and compliant with the TR-069 standard?

And how to install it (or port it) on OpenWRT linux platforms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tested these cwmp client, I found that EasyCwmp is the only one which contain all required RPC and fully conform with TR069 standard.
This table show the supported RPC by each cwmp client 
[image]

[image: RPR Acronym]

Answer (score 0):

EasyCWMP is a complete opensource project.
This link can help you to install it:
http://www.easycwmp.org/index.php/manual

New updated link : 
http://www.easycwmp.org/install.html